# ngx-dropzone: show preview thumbnail of existing files

Tags: angular, dropzone

I have used ngx-dropzone to use upload file, now in the edit mode, I want to show the existing file in the drop box and display the same when upload file

```
{
    "name": "File1.JPG",
    "size": 213213123,
    "fileUrl": "https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/spring-flower-collection_23-2148853687.jpg?w=2000",
}


<ngx-dropzone-image-preview ngProjectAs="ngx-dropzone-preview" *ngFor="let f of files" [file]="f">
  <ngx-dropzone-label>{{ f.name }} ({{ f.type }})</ngx-dropzone-label>
</ngx-dropzone-image-preview>
```

[example thumbnail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s33br.png)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to create dropzone directive

```
  @ViewChild(DropzoneDirective) dropzoneDirectiveRef?: DropzoneDirective;
```

after that in ngAfterViewInit

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
       const images: Array<any> = this.products.images;
         // is images a true array and not empty
       if (Array.isArray(images) && images.length > 0) {
       images.forEach(image => {
        // cuting out the extension from filename
       let extension: any = image.split('.');
       extension = extension.slice(extension.length - 1, 
       extension.length).join('.');
       const mockFile = {
       name: image.name,
       size: image.size,
       type: `image/${extension}`,
       accepted: true,
       dataURL: `${environment.storageLink}${image.url}`,
      };

     const dropzoneInstance = this.dropzoneDirectiveRef?.dropzone();
     dropzoneInstance.emit('addedfile', mockFile);
     dropzoneInstance.options.maxFiles = 5; //You can change as your 
                                           // requirement
     dropzoneInstance.createThumbnailFromUrl(mockFile, 200, null, 
     'contain', true, function (thumbnail: any) {
      dropzoneInstance.files.push(thumbnail);
      dropzoneInstance.emit('thumbnail', mockFile, thumbnail);
     },
      'Anonymous'
     );
     dropzoneInstance.emit('complete', mockFile);
     });
    }}}
```

[image]

for your reference: https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-dropzone-wrapper/issues/99#issuecomment-443081425